# "if", and "elif" chain versus a plain "if" chain

Tags: python, if-statement

I was wondering, why is using `elif` necessary when you could just do this?

```
if True:
    ...
if False:
    ...
...
```

Comment: `elif` is not necessary, it is syntactic sugar.

Comment: It wouldn't do the same. Hint: "el" stands for "else".

Comment: @Hyperboreus That is just plain wrong, you better delete your comment.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Seriously?

Comment: @PascalvKooten So `if A: x(); elif B: y()` is not the same as `if A: x(); if not A and B: y ()`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That's entirely wrong, I'm afraid. What if the code **in** the `if` branch disabled `A`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters et al: Please enlighten me with an example that can only be expressed by using `elif`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus See Martijn's answer.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Please see my comment above.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I added an example of why `elif` is more than just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Now you are just going hypothetical; sure there are ways I can implement `for` with a `while` loop too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Very valid point. Thank you.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Even without Martijn's example, we're talking about some fairly serious sugar. Do you really think anyone would actually write `if A: x(); if not A and B: y(); if not A and not B and C: z()` etc.? You might as well say "oh Python is completely unnecessary, because it's just syntactic sugar for C; and by the way, there's nothing essential about C, because we can just program in assembly...."

Comment: To be fair to @Hyperboreus, he probably should've asked the question `elif` vs `else: … if`

Comment: @kojiro: Agreed. The **real** benefit of `elif` is that it reduces nesting (indentation) levels.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have misread the question. I thought it was about the "need" of having an elif statement, and not the benefits.

Comment: @Hyperboreus that's okay.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'd use `elif` when you want to ensure that only *one* branch is picked:

```
foo = 'bar'
spam = 'eggs'

if foo == 'bar':
    # do this
elif spam == 'eggs':
    # won't do this.
```

Compare this with:

```
foo = 'bar'
spam = 'eggs'

if foo == 'bar':
    # do this
if spam == 'eggs':
    # *and* do this.
```

With just `if` statements, the options are not exclusive.

This also applies when the `if` branch *changes* the program state such that the `elif` test might be true too:

```
foo = 'bar'

if foo == 'bar':
    # do this
    foo = 'spam'
elif foo == 'spam':
    # this is skipped, even if foo == 'spam' is now true
    foo = 'ham'
```

Here `foo` will be set to `'spam'`.

```
foo = 'bar'

if foo == 'bar':
    # do this
    foo = 'spam'
if foo == 'spam':
    # this is executed when foo == 'bar' as well, as 
    # the previous if statement changed it to 'spam'.
    foo = 'ham'
```

Now `foo` is set to `'spam'`, then to `'ham'`.

Technically speaking, `elif` is part of the (compound) `if` statement; Python picks the *first* test in a series of `if` / `elif` branches that tests as true, or the `else` branch (if present) if none are true. Using a separate `if` statement starts a new selection, independent of the previous `if` compound statement.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.count` is a generator that gives you a new value each time it's called, so it's useful for illustrating this kind of thing.

```
from itertools import count
c = count()
print(next(c)) # 0
print(next(c)) # 1
print(next(c)) # 2
if True:
  print(next(c)) # 3
if True:
  print(next(c)) # 4
elif True:
  print(next(c)) # … not called
print(next(c)) # 5
```

The last value would have to be 6 for the `elif` to be the same as the `if`. But generators can also be "used up", which means you need to be able to avoid checking them twice.

```
if 6 == next(c):
  print('got 6') # Printed!
if (7 == next(c)) and not (6 == next(c)):
  print('got 7') # Also printed!
```

is not the same as

```
if 9 == next(c):
  print('got 9') # printed
elif 10 == next(c):
  print('got 10') # not printed!
```