# What's the main difference between 'if' and 'else if'?

Tags: python, if-statement

For e.g.. 

According to some experts,

The conditions here are mutually exclusive:

```
if(n>0):
    print "Number is Positive"
if(n<0):
    print "Number is Negative"
if(n==0):
    print "Number is ZERO"
```

It would be better to rewrite with elif and else:

```
 if n > 0:
    print "Number is Positive"
 elif n < 0:
    print "Number is Negative"
 else:
    print "Number is ZERO"
```

So I just want to ask the question that , Is there any difference between **' if '** and **' elif '** . I know the basic difference between ' if ' and ' elif '. But I just want to know  , Why some novice programmers prefer ' elif ' over ' if '?

Comment: Also see [elif and if VS just if](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23230044)

Answer (score 23):

The first form `if-if-if` tests *all* conditions, whereas the second `if-elif-else` tests only as many as needed: if it finds one condition that is `True`, it stops and doesn't evaluate the rest. In other words: `if-elif-else` is used when the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Let's write an example. if you want to determine the greatest value between three numbers, we could test to see if one is greater or equal than the others until we find the maximum value - but once that value is found, there is no need to test the others:

```
greatest = None
if a >= b and a >= c:
    greatest = a
elif b >= a and b >= c:
    greatest = b
else:
    greatest = c
print greatest
```

Alternatively, we could *assume* one initial value to be the greatest, and test each of the other values in turn to see if the assumption holds true, updating the assumed value as needed:

```
greatest = None
if a > greatest:
    greatest = a
if b > greatest:
    greatest = b
if c > greatest:
    greatest = c
print greatest
```

As you can see, both `if-if-if` and `if-elif-else` are useful, depending on what you need to do. In particular, the second of my examples is more useful, because it'd be easy to put the conditional inside a loop - so it doesn't matter how many numbers we have, whereas in the first example we'd need to write many conditions by hand for each additional number.

Comment: Ok You mean Processing Difference.

Comment: @J.Smith.JJJ they're different behaviors, to be clear. Sometimes you need one, sometimes the other - it depends on the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @J.Smith.JJJ I added an example, to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 12):

You can chain `if` with `elif` and finish with an `else` if none of the conditions in the chain were met. When checking through the statements, it will find the first matching one and execute the instructions within that block, then break from the if/elif/else block

```
n = 6
if n % 2 == 0:
  print('divisible by 2')
elif n % 3 == 0:
  print('divisible by 3')
else:
  print('not divisible by two or three')
```

this would print

```
divisible by 2
```

However, say you replace that `elif` above with an `if` and remove the `else` clause...

```
divisible by 2
divisible by 3
```

the `elif` chains the statements and chooses the first appropriate one.

Comment: Best way.. (using Example)

Comment: this example really does demonstrate the main difference between if and elif, very clear.