# Why doesn't else statement work instead of if (all previous cases aren't true)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

So I have a list **mem** that represents memory and in this loop I'm searching for **dataSize** number of empty spaces which are represented as **"-"** in memory.
Logic is following:
*First search for **"-"** (empty slot), then mark it as starting location **writeStart** and then see how much more empty slots I have after that position and count it as **writeSize**. **Found** is then set on True if I have found enough slots or else loop breaks and returns to original loop that searches for another empty slot as **writeStart**.Then I use **writeStart** and **writeSize** as parameters to write in memory after this loop.*
This code works correctly but if I switch third **if** statement with an **else** it won't work anymore. Why? Thank you in advance.

```
for i in range(len(mem)):
    if(mem[i] == "-"):
        writeStart = i
        writeSize = 0
        for j in range(i, len(mem)):
            if(mem[j] == "-"):
                writeSize += 1
            if(writeSize == dataSize):
                found = True
                break
            if((mem[j] != "-") & (writeSize != dataSize)): #if switched with an else: error
                i = j
                break
    if(found):
    break
```

Comment: Use elif instead of if.

Comment: But why can't I use else?

Comment: else can not have a condition. Only use else if you want to run code if the if didn’t run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "third if" you mean the one that has both the `mem[j]` condition and the `writeSize` condition, the problem is that the `else` clause would only be the alternative to the `writeSize == dataSize` if, not to both of them.

I think you could restructure the code like this:

```
for j in range(i, len(mem)):
    if (mem[j] == "-"):
        writeSize += 1
        if (writeSize == dataSize):
            found = True
            break
    else:
        i = j
        break
```

because checking `writeSize` only matters if you increment it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to this link :

[What's the main difference between 'if' and 'else if'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703446/whats-the-main-difference-between-if-and-else-if)

You need to use elif - the reason is explained well on the link

Comment: I have the case when both first ifs must be executed.

Comment: I am copy pasting the reason it is not working from the link I provided. Hope it helps: The first form if-if-if tests all conditions, whereas the second if-elif-else tests only as many as needed: if it finds one condition that is True, it stops and doesn't evaluate the rest. In other words:  if-elif-else is used when the conditions are mutually exclusive